# Convert ASCII to Unsigned Int and Vice Versa

Tags: c++, ascii

I am reading a large file with several different fields on each line. By analogy, you can think of each line of the file as representing an employee and one of the fields contains the department name that they work in. However, the department name can be made up of any set of 4-5 ASCII characters (e.g. "1234", "ABCD", "P+0$i".

Currently, I am (naively) storing the characters as an std::string but I've noticed that I've been performing a lot of time-consuming string comparisons. Thus, I would like to read the field from the file, convert the string into a number (maybe an unsigned int?), and then later do many numerical comparisons (and avoid the string comparison). Of course, I will need a way to convert the number back into a string for output.

Most of my online searches bring up "convert string to number" which discusses the use of using stringstream to convert a number string to an int of some sort. This isn't particularly helpful and I can't seem to come up with a proper search query to find a solution. Can anybody please point me to a relevant source or provide a way to perform this conversion?

Comment: You are doing I/O from/to disk and memory allocations (by using std::string). These are slow operations. How did you come to the conclusion that it is string comparison that is slowing you down?

Comment: From the sound of it you seem to have a search algorithm problem more than a string comparison performance issue. You might want to consider storing your data into a `std::unordered_map` for O(1) lookup or keeping it in sorted order so you can use `std::binary_search` for O(log(n)) time.

Comment: search for hash functions, std::map, std::binary_search and std::unordered_map.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have up to 5 ASCII characters, then the simplest approach is to pad it out to 8 with whatever character you like, then `*reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(the_id.data())`.

If you want to fit the character representation in to a 32 bit int, you need to do considerably more work: simply discarding the high order bit (possible because ASCII codes are 0-127) still leaves 7*5 = 35 bits - too many for a 32-bit type.  Assuming the ids don't contain any control codes (i.e. ASCII codes 0-31), you can achieve the packing with *base-96 encoding* like this:

```
unsigned base = 128 - 32;
// pad c out to 5 characters if necessary.
unsigned idnum = (((((c[0] - 32) * base + (c[1] - 32)) * base + (c[2] - 32)) * base + (c[3] - 32)) * base + (c[4] - 32)) * base + c[5] - 32;
```

You may find it easier to read with a loop:

```
unsigned idnum = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    idnum *= base;
    idnum += c[i] - ' ';
}
```

Unpacking the number back to the string value is done with `% base` to get the last digit, then `/ base` to prepare for getting the next....

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a map with department name -> integer mappings somewhere. Depending on how fixed the department names are, either read them from a configuration file or define the map statically. Create the inverse mapping afterwards to map integer -> string when needed.
2. While reading your file, lookup the associated key in the mapping and store it in your data structure.
3. When needed, lookup the department name in the inverse map

Answer (score 0):

Given that std::string equality operations are actually efficient for data of arbitrary lengths and you need to retain the actual string value, I feel that you might want to look elsewhere for performance improvements. Looking over your requirements it looks like you just need to have a better search efficiency for your objects. The `std::unordered_map` container is likely a good candidate for use. It is an associative container that has a constant time for lookups via a key. You can store other collections of your data as the value type for the unordered_map and set the associated key to what ever you want to look it up by. Here is an example of some types that enable looking up a matching subset of your data via a string.

```
struct Employee;
typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Employee>> Employees;
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, Employees>  EmployeeByLookup;
```

You could then lookup all employees that match a given key value like this.

```
static EmployeeByLookup byDepartment;

Employees& GetDepartmentList(const std::string& department)
{
    return byDepartment[department];
}
```

If you need to look up your object by value instead of via an associative key then I would suggest that you look at `std::unordered_set`. It also has an average complexity of constant time for lookups. You can create your own hash function for your object if you need to optimize the internal hash performance.

I created a [simple application](http://ideone.com/N0c6iW) using the `unordered_map` example. Take a look if your interested.

Answer (score -1):

C++11 has `std::stoi`. Other than that, you can use a stringstream for conversions:

```
std::istringstream iss("1234");
int x;
if ( iss >> x )
    std::cout << "Got " << x << "\n";
else
    std::cout << "String did not contain a number\n";
```

You can do other stream extractions from `iss` just like you are used to doing with `cin`.

I'm not sure why you consider the stringstream advice to be "not very useful"?

Comment: As stated, the string can be ANY set of ASCII characters. So I want to be able to convert "ABCD", "1234", or "P+0$i" into a unique number and then be able to convert it back into its original string.

Comment: Why? Your original post suggests you think a numeric comparison will be faster, but actually it will be just the same and you waste time with all your conversion operations.  If you really must, then `unsigned long x = (unsigned char)s[0] * 0x1000000 + (unsigned char)s[1] * 0x10000 + (unsigned char)s[2] * 0x100 + (unsigned char)s[3];`. You can extend that to `unsigned long long` if you want to have strings of up to 8 characters. If you have strings longer than 8, then you have more possible strings than possible numbers so this isn't going to work.

Comment: Looks like you want a hash code for each of these strings. If you know the set of strings before, you could compute an optimal hash function, otherwise you have to live with collisions.

But even if your hash function is optimal, it may not be faster because it has to compute the hash code for every comparison. You may see better results with an ordered data structure, e.g. a std::map with your string as the key.

Comment: @Jens: we do "know the set of strings before" - it's the set of 4-5 character ASCII strings, for which we can calculate a perfect hash function (in the technical sense where "perfect" means collision free for those keys) as per my answer.  "has to compute the hash code for every comparison" - not true... you store hashes in your container for reuse however many times, and hash the incoming key once.  For all that, I very much doubt the string comparisons are problematically slow - would want to see profiling evidence before recommending a change, and `std::map` is commonly a good solution.

Comment: @Tony D
You have to compute the hash value once for the elements in the container, and then for every new object to compare to, if you store hash codes in the objects. If you don't, you will have to compute them for the comparison. I did not say that a sorted container will be faster, but it can be, depending on data distribution, complexity of the hash function etc. If it is critical, it should be measured. And then, a sorted vector or array may be even faster than std::map...

Comment: @Jens: "*If you don't*, you will have to compute them for the comparison" - and if you don't put petrol in your car it won't be faster than walking.  Anyway, hashing the key is a choice orthogonal to the choice of container - you could still store the data in a sorted container or `std::map`... nobody's even mentioned hash tables in any comments I've read, nor did the question.

Comment: @Tony D I usually would not use a hash function as key in a sorted container because it is not made to work with hash values. Collisions will mess it up. So, I tend to say that hash tables imply hash functions, and sorted containers are a different concept.

Comment: @Jens: as above, we can easily achieve perfect hashing here (using base-96 encoding as per my answer) so there are no collisions.  Sure hash tables imply hash functions; that does not mean hash functions imply hash tables.  A hash function just maps a key in the data domain to whatever value's useful for storage and retrieval... typically a shorter value that's cheap to compare, and ideally a collision free value and possibly contiguous values - depending on exactly what you're doing with it.